# Why does this script not stop but keeps spamming a and enter?

Tags: python

Why does this script not stop but keeps spamming a and enter?

```py
import keyboard
import pyautogui

santtu = True
oliver = False


while santtu:
    if keyboard.is_pressed("e"):
        oliver = False
    if keyboard.is_pressed("s"):
        oliver = True

    while oliver:
        pyautogui.press("a", interval=1)
        pyautogui.press("Enter", interval=1)
```

these were all the methods i tried:

```py
  if keyboard.is_pressed("e"):
        global oliver
        oliver = False
        quit()
        exit()
        break
```

Comment: If your variable `oliver` is ever set to `True`, then your `while` loop will never exit.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? It's not clear from the code what the plan is.

Comment: The moment `oliver` becomes `True`, you enter an infinite loop. There is no way for that variable to become `False` again within the loop.

Comment: Since [`quit` and `exit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#quit) were mentioned I'd like to quote what the documentation says about these functions: "They are useful for the interactive interpreter shell and should not be used in programs."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting stuck in the `while oliver` loop. The program will remain in that loop until `oliver` is `False`. But given you change `oliver` to `False` outside the loop, it never becomes `False` again.

Try changing the `while oliver` to the below . This will cause the program to check the conditional, execute the code within it if `oliver` is `True`, then continue to the next iteration of the `while santtu` loop.

```py
if oliver:
    pyautogui.press("a", interval=1)
    pyautogui.press("Enter", interval=1)
```